# How to connect my REST API to another API

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a REST API (API_1) written in Django-rest-framework. I want to connect it to another REST API (API_2) so that API_1 will be extension of API_2. API_1 extends the base User model and provides some additional features. I do not want to create new tables for users, but just use the existing users in API_2. Do you have any suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: Your question seems to be ambigious. Please change the `My API` and `Another REST API` to something like  API_1, API_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I formulated my question incorrectly. I wanted to build an API that uses two databases (one default and second managed by another API).